# Передача InputStream в Activity

Tags: android-sdk, android, activity

Каким образом можно отправить `InputStream` в `Activity`?

У меня имеется `RecyclerView`, в который при нажатие на *item* выводиться контент. В Activity, которая вызывается, нужно передать `InputStream[]`, содержащийся в `listAttachStream`.

```
rv.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new ItemRecycler.RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), new ItemRecycler.RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        String theme = adapter.subject[position];
                        String content = adapter.content[position];
                        String date = adapter.dateMail[position];
                        String email = adapter.email[position];
                        String nameSender = adapter.from[position];

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ItemMail.class);
                        intent.putExtra(ItemMail.SUBJECT, theme);
                        intent.putExtra(ItemMail.CONTENT, content);
                        intent.putExtra(ItemMail.DATE, date);
                        intent.putExtra(ItemMail.EMAIL, email);
                        intent.putExtra(ItemMail.NAMESENDER, nameSender);
                        intent.putExtra(ItemMail.MAIL, "входящие");

                        for (int k = 0; k < listAttach.size(); k++){
                            for (int m = 0; m < listAttach.get(k).length; m++) {
                                if (!(listAttach.get(k)[m] == null) && (k == position)) {

                                    intent.putExtra(ItemMail.ATTACH, listAttach.get(position));
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        for (int k = 0; k < listAttachStream.size(); k++){
                            for (int m = 0; m < listAttachStream.get(k).length; m++) {
                                if (!(listAttachStream.get(k)[m] == null) && (k == position)) {
                                    intent.putExtra(ItemMail.ATTACHSTREAM, listAttachStream.get(position));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onItemLongPress(View childView, int position) {
                    }
                })
        );
```

Пытался сделать через `Parceable` — не помогло. Какие есть способы это сделать?

Comment: можно подробнее, откуда отправить? что имеете на данный момент, если подкрепите кодом, так вообще будет замечательно)

Comment: Мне нужно отправить InputStream[] в Activity)

Comment: А не проще отправить position (или лучше id) в activity, которая сама все что нужно достанет? И вообще stream'ы у вас в адаптере все открытые же? А кто их закрывает и в какой момент? Неаккуратненько как-то.

Answer (score 2):

InputStream - это не сериализуемый класс, по этому вы не сможете передать обьекты данного класса Активити, да в принципе вам это и не нужно. Как правило, InputStream - это незавершенное действие. То есть я имею в виду, что InputStream использую для того, чтобы подтянуть какие то данные, Если ваш InputStream - это какой то файл или изображение, то вы получаете массив Байтов, если же InputStream - это текст, то вы получаете от него String. Вам нужно завершить данную работу. То есть вам необходимо получить Строку, Или байты, или Битмап (Это зависит от того, что вам нужно) из вашего InputStream, и уже его передать в Активити